# how to hide div tag using javascript with an If condition

Tags: javascript, php

I want to hide  a div tag after checking If condition. It means I checked session roles with If condition, and then make a javascript to hide a div tag. Can you guys have any code look similar like I want.

```js
<?php
if ($_SESSION['role'] == 'Moderator' || $_SESSION['role'] == 'Editor') {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
 
---code hidden div tag here

</script>
<?php }?>
```

something like this, because I don't want these roles "Moderator, Editor" see or do action on the div tag I want. Can you guys help me out. Thank you!

Comment: Does it help? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp

Comment: You don't need to use javascript because you don't want to toggle, you just don't want it to exist for these roles. Just use the condition on the part where you output the div and output them or not.

Answer (score 1):

The JS code would be like this:

```
//Get the div
    var mydiv = document.getElementById("myDIV");
//Set display to none
    mydiv.style.display = "none";
```

You can also do this without JavaScript like this:

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION['role'] == 'Moderator' || $_SESSION['role'] == 'Editor') {
?>
  <div id="myDiv"></div>
<?php }?>
```

Place the div between the php if-statement